# saving mail attachment with PowerAutomate to sharepoint corrupts the file

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am trying to build a flow based on the PowerAutomate template

> Create Planner task and add attachments to SharePoint on new email
> arrival

This template works fine, in that it saves all the mail attachments to my sharepoint. But it only shows the link to the last attachment in the task.

I have worked around it, by adding a string variable and appending all the sharepoint paths to this variable.

With my Flow, everything runs smoothly. But the stored files are about 10%- 20% bigger in size than the original and they turn out to be corrupted.

The only difference I can spot in the saving of the file is as follows:

Template section has "get attachment" and the according "body('get attachment'):
[image: "get attachment" within template flow]

While my in my version I can only select "get attachment (V2)" and the corresponding "body('get attachment (V2)')
[image: "get attachment" within custom flow]

There is an option with V2 that allows or disallows chunking, but there is no effect on my filesize.
The other difference is, that I have my flow create a different folder based on the task ID, since there where errors, if the same name attachment came a second time. But I have tried my flow without the added folders and there is no difference in file size.

The original files:
[image: original filesize]

and the corrupted files:
[image: corrupted filesize]

It makes no difference if I use the sharepoint link provided through the flow to my new planner task, or if I open the files directly within sharepoint. The result is an error.

Can anyone guess, why my flow seems to store something more within the file and thus corrupting it? I can provide the other parts of the flow in more detail too. Here is the overview of my custom flow:

[image: upper part of custom flow]
[image: lower part of custom flow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer after rewriting it from scratch:

Using the old template had me looking for the wrong information when adding the attachment content to sharepoint. I had always searched for "body" which was used in the template and gave me this

[image]

But searching for attachment the dynamic content actually showed me the right pieces. I am not sure, if I missed it before, or if recoding a template hid them somehow. With the rewrite from scratch I found this:

[image]

So, to make a long story short: Use "Content Bytes" of the "Get_Attachment_(V2)" Method and everything works fine.